# how to search through DB by month

Tags: php, sql

So I'm making a website where you can post events. The date is done through three drop down menus (month, day, year). The values are saved in number form in my SQL table (ie 12/7/2012). I have a search page where there is a drop down menu for month. I want to make a search function that searches and finds all the events in the month the user chose.

How do I make my function versatile to any of the 12 months that could be clicked?

This is my attempt at the php

> $month = $_GET['month'];
>
> $monthresult = query("SELECT * FROM events WHERE month LIKE '%" .$month. "%' ");

Comment: So you're using a VARCHAR column to store dates rather than one of the standard date column types that allow you to actually manipulate dates, and do such things as search by month easily

Comment: Incidentally, what do you expect to happen in a years time, when you'll have December 2013 as well as December 2012?

Comment: I never even thought of that! Do you have any advice to do this better?

Comment: Start by looking at the date types in MySQL (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/datetime.html); and look at eithe rforcing the user to select a year as well if they select a month, or defaulting year to the current year if a month is selected

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is the best way to make it, but You should do something like this

```
$monthresult = query("SELECT * FROM events WHERE month LIKE '%/$month/%'");
```

Month is in the middle so by using slashes we make sure that it won't affect date.

Comment: Is there a better way of doing it? I am new to coding so I am unfamiliar with more ways of approaching this

Answer (score 0):

ok i figured it out and it works perfectly

> $month = $_GET['month'];
>
> $monthresult = query("SELECT * FROM events WHERE month LIKE '$month' ");

and i am using INT to save the date in my table